# Logging Linux Terminal Output to Files by Date?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, shell, logging

I am interested in creating or using a method to log all terminal output from my python script to a logfile, but I would like to have the logs automatically start a new file at the start of each new day. So far, i'm aware I can write a shell script to do something along the lines of:

```
script test.txt 
python -yourscriptnamehere-
```

However I am interested in having this script become something where the script can end the recording, and start a new recording on the new day, with a new filename, preferably with the date as a log name.

Is this doable, and if so, where would I go from here?

Note: the reason I don't just log all my prints to a file in the python script is because i am using the logging library to get debug information on my connection to a server, and i don't seem to have control of that process.

Comment: You don't have control of the logging library in *your* python script? The two easiest ways to to this that I can think of are to use the logging library to create new logs every day (from within your script), or to use `journalctl` to capture the script output and dates (which may require root, I'd have to look it up).

Answer (score 0):

Objective: Log all terminal output from the script to a log file using python.

Solution: Before logging, check for today's date, and if today's file exists, write there, and if it doesn't, create one.

```
import time    
import sys
import os
import subprocess

logDir = "log/"        //Create a log dir beforehand
p = subprocess.Popen("[script you want to log]", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  //Specify the script you want to log
while 1:
  line = p.stdout.readline() // read stdout line by line
  today = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") // get today's date
  filePath = logDir + today // file path as log dir + today's date
  if os.path.isfile(filePath): // if file exists
    with open(filePath, "a") as logFile: write at the end of the file
      logFile.write(line)
  else:    // if file does not exist
    logFile = open(filePath, "w") // create a new file 
    logFile.write(line) // write
```